# List of objects of different classes C++

Tags: c++, class, list

I already figured out to use polymorphism and have the list store the pointer to the baseClass, but after successfully placing it there, I would like to know what class the object was originally. I am using templates for the classes, and wanted to have an another field which would be an enum of basic types.

Now the question: is there a way to check (during runtime or during compilation) an

```
(if T == int)  
   field = INT
```

I though maybe something with the preprocessor but I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: You probably just about need to show at least some of the code and what you're really trying to do to have hope of getting a meaningful answer. Trying to find the type over which a template was instantiated usually indicates a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use operator `typeid`.

For example, if `T` is a pointer to a base class:

```
if (typeid(SomeDerivedClass) == typeid(*T))
...
```

(It is somewhat unclear for me why you speak about `int` in connection with polymorphism.  `int` cannot be derived from.)

Answer (score 4):

The whole idea behind polymorphism is to hide the specific implementation making it transparent in your program flow. Using type of class as an indicator will make your code bloat with `if` statements and will be harder to maintain.

I suggest you reconsider your design and make an abstract class with the intended behavior methods and use this class type as the list objects type. Than for each object call the interface method (which was declared in the abstract class and implemented in the deriving classes)

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is known as type traits. They allow you to determine and act on the attributes of a specific type. You could start with `std::is_integral()` and `std::is_floating_point()` and build from there depending on your requirements.

```
enum Type
{
    Unknown,
    Integral,
    Float
};

....

Type field = Unknown;

if(std::is_integral<T>::value)
{
    field = Integral;
}

else if(std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
{
    field = Float;
}
```

Comment: There is one problem with this: the `enum` is declared in each instantiation of the template, and `Foo<char>::Type` is thus a different type than `Foo<int>::Type`. You should declare the `enum` outside the template and, optionally, import it using a `typedef`. Furthermore, though it works, the translation from type to `enum` should be done by overloading a function instead of providing a single function with runtime checks (though in practice they should be optimized out). For more complex, where an action on `T` is required, you will run into issues with this pattern.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Didn't even think about the placement of Type. I whittled it down a little to more closely match the OP's example. Lot less around it.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ preprocessor knows nothing about C++.  It is a generic symbol manipulator which can be used with most any programming language, or for that matter, any text processing application, such as a feature of word or equation layout processing.

You might look into the [**typeid** operator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RTTI#typeid) as one way to build such a mechanism, though heed the *Misuses of RTTI* section further down on that page.